# Simplifying a Summation : $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{4^i}{(i!)^2}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How can I simplify the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{4^i}{(i!)^2}$$

I cannot think of anyway to simplify this.

Comment: This summation is equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2^i}{i!})^2 $ but that doesn't give much insight. Wolfram Alpha also doesn't yield a nice closed form unless you are interested in using bessel functions/other non-elementary stuff: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(i%3D0,+infinity,+4%5Ei%2F(i!)%5E2)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Yes I am interested in the bessel function. Can you give me some info on this and how wolfram alpha comes to this?

Comment: If you use the series definition of the bessel function, then it follows by definition, see @CountIblis 's link. What you are then interested is asking, how is this series formula derived in the first place from the Bessel Differential Equation?

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, since the expansion of the modified Bessel function of the first kind write (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html))$$I_\nu(z)=\left(\frac z2 \right)^\nu \,\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac z2 \right)^{2k} }{k! \,\Gamma(\nu+k+1)}$$ then
$$I_o(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac z2 \right)^{2k} }{k! \,\Gamma(k+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac z2 \right)^{2k} }{(k!)^2 }$$ and, as a result, $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{(i!)^2}=I_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)$$ which cannot reduce to elementary functions.

For your case, the numerical evaluation would converge very fast since $$u_n=\frac {4^n}{(n!)^2}\implies \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{4}{(n+1)^2}$$ I give you below the numerical values for suucessive $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approx} \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 5 & 5 \\
 2 & 9 & 9 \\
 3 & \frac{97}{9} & 10.7777777777778 \\
 4 & \frac{101}{9} & 11.2222222222222 \\
 5 & \frac{847}{75} & 11.2933333333333 \\
 6 & \frac{4577}{405} & 11.3012345679012 \\
 7 & \frac{1121429}{99225} & 11.3018795666415 \\
 8 & \frac{373811}{33075} & 11.3019198790627 \\
 9 & \frac{90836089}{8037225} & 11.3019218697996 \\
 10 & \frac{2270902241}{200930625} & 11.3019219494291 \\
 11 & \frac{1221240761}{108056025} & 11.3019219520614 \\
 12 & \frac{353287505863}{31259064375} & 11.3019219521346 \\
 13 & \frac{417939119435993}{36979473155625} & 11.3019219521363
\end{array}
\right)$$ As you can see, using seven terms, we already obtain six correct significant figures.